# Program to display pattern?

Tags: java

I would like to generate a pattern like this

```
                 1234554321
                 1234  4321
                 123    321
                 12      21
                 1        1
                 12      21
                 123    321
                 1234  4321
                 1234554321
```

by using this code

```
public class Pattren {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i,j,n;
    n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++)
            System.out.print(j);
        for(j=0;j<2*i;j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for(j=n-i;j>0;j--)
            System.out.print(j);
    }
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
            System.out.print(j);
        for(j=i;j>0;j--)
            System.out.print(j);
    }
    }

}
```

This is what I get:

```
  1234554321
  1234  4321
  123    321
  12      21
  1        1
  1221
  123321
  12344321
  1234554321
```

Could you help me to fix that problem?

Comment: You forgot to insert the `for` loop to insert the blanks in the second case, i.e. within `for(i=2;i<=n;i++)`.

Comment: I wonder if a _typo_ is worthy of multiple upvotes!

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to print spaces in the bottom part. You can use:

```
for (j = 2 * (n - i); j > 0; j--) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
1234554321
1234  4321
123    321
12      21
1        1
1        1
12      21
123    321
1234  4321
1234554321
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printPattern(5);
}
public static void printPattern(int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printLine(count, i);
    }
    for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        printLine(count, i);
    }
}
private static void printLine(int count, int missing) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
        boolean isMissing = i > count - missing;
        System.out.print(isMissing ? " " : String.valueOf(i));
    }
    for (int i = count; i > 0; --i) {
        boolean isMissing = i > count - missing;
        System.out.print(isMissing ? " " : String.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

printPattern(9) =

```
123456789987654321
12345678  87654321
1234567    7654321
123456      654321
12345        54321
1234          4321
123            321
12              21
1                1
1                1
12              21
123            321
1234          4321
12345        54321
123456      654321
1234567    7654321
12345678  87654321
123456789987654321
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this in a single statement in C# just for fun. Sharing for everyone's amusement.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
          Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Select(x => Math.Abs(5 - x)).Select(i =>
               string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, i).Select(x => x.ToString())) +
               new string(' ', (5 - i) * 2) +
               string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(1, i).Select(x => (i - x + 1).ToString()))
                        ).Where(s => s.Trim().Length > 0)));
```

I actually wanted to post it in java but didn't know if there's some equivalent of LINQ in Java or not. C# is quite close in syntax and may work without any changes there if `Enumerable.Range()` or an equivalent could be located.

Answer (score 0):

You did not print spaces for the lower part. The code below works fine :

```
public class Pattren {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i,j,n;
    n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++)
            System.out.print(j);
        for(j=0;j<2*i;j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for(j=n-i;j>0;j--)
            System.out.print(j);
    }
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
            System.out.print(j);
        for (j = 2*(n - i); j > 0; j--)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for(j=i;j>0;j--)
            System.out.print(j);
    }
    }

}
```